# In Google Chrome/ Chromium net-internals events, what is "DISK_CACHE_ENTRY"?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

What are the DISK_CACHE_ENTRY urls in chrome://net-internals/#events, and why are they happening when no remote resources are being asked for?

A google search mostly shows bug reports and source code — is there documentation on this event type available anywhere?

*More info:*

I am running Chromium Version 43.0.2357.81 Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit).

The DISK_CACHE_ENTRY urls seem to be coming from my history. For example, I have no remote resources open, but I see this event appear (probably from a past Google Maps visit):

```
6409    DISK_CACHE_ENTRY    http://maps.gstatic.com/maps-api-v3/api/js/21/4/common.js
```

To rule out that they are one of the requests in user-configurable Chrome operations, I disabled all extensions, uchecked all options under "Privacy", and disabled all account sync options. I opened only two tabs:

- chrome://net-internals/#events
- http://localhost/ (a simple directory listing with no remote urls)

The events still happen whenever I refresh the localhost tab.

Answer (score 1):

This page may provide some of the documentation you are looking for: https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache, though it isn't too detailed. Note that they also mention there is an upcoming switch to Disk [Cache 3.0](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/design-documents/network-stack/disk-cache/disk-cache-v3) (not sure when exactly).

In terms of the behavior you're seeing, my guess is that you have the setting enabled to allow chrome to preloads data from your history ([docs](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/114836?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)) to speed up the browsing experience, but that's just a guess.